# How to rewrite url for pictures from http to https in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I use ssl in web-site on WordPress. But when web-site works on https there is mixed-contnet problem. How to rewrite url for pictures from http to https in WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your blog's URL in your WP admin interface to `https://...`

If your posts contain images, you'll need to edit them manually or use a WP plugin to rewrite those image URLs to https. For example, you can use the [Insecure Content Fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) plugin.

Edit: Thanks for the downvote. Could you explain what's missing in my answer via a comment? Thanks!

Comment: I found the place in database where this picture's url I search is situated (it's a string in tab wp_options), tried to rewrite it manually, but after this my whole tab wp_options didn't work. I continued to work only when I edit this url back to http.

Comment: Don't edit the WordPress database manually. It contains checksums for the length of content. Have you tried the addon that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: The plugin still works in 2024, it managed to edit those HTTP images urls into HTTPS.

Comment: Changing URL results an Error: too many redirects. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

when website opens with https; all request goes to the server using https only. Pictures are no exception. But as far as your problem is concerned you might have place the url of images using http. For example your website is test.com. So, you might have placed image as

```
 <img src="http://test.com/imagename" />
```

Now, all you to do is find these url and make changes in them. Ideal way to call a url in wordpress

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/headers/image.jpg" />
```

I hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to test your url here in this site https://www.whynopadlock.com/ which will show all the path's which are not HTTPS:// by this you can identify at where you need to change the things.

And also you may include this code in .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you can used plugin like FORCE SSL which also works to change non HTTP to HTTPS